# Cloud-based security testing?

Tags: security

We want to regularly test our web apps for vulnerabilities - we have a BurpSuite licence but would like to look into the possibility of using an online solution.

Benefits as we see them:

- Little/no staff training required
- It's always up to date (checking the latest known vuns)
- It may be more cost-effective

Has anyone used such a solution before? How was the experience over manual testing with a local app such as BurpSuite?

Comment: Perhaps http://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your regular testing involve running purely automated scans or manual analysis using BurpSuite?

A cloud-based scanner isn't going to offer as much interactivity as running BurpSuite locally. Manual analysis is important for analyzing design issues, authorization problems, or logic errors. What a fully automated scanner will (or should) do is take care of tedious tests for vulns like SQL injection and XSS. (Think of it as finding implementation problems rather than design problems.)

A cloud-based scanner could be a drop-in replacement for BurpSuite scans you're running "out of the box" -- i.e. not using much configuration. But it should never the less complement, not replace, good manual testing. This can be a benefit cost-wise.

While a cloud-based scanner can be "always up to date", in reality there are very few new web vulns. For example, the OWASP Top 10 has only changed a little in the last 7 years. The updated vulns will help if you're mostly using open source or commercial web apps, but they won't have any bearing on the apps you build in house.

(FYI, my perspective comes from working on a cloud-based scanner.)

Comment: Good answer - I think were going to take a look at Google's Skipfish in the interim